# Unity 3d Animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 3d

I m a newbie to Unity3d and was just playing with unity animation, i was trying to implement 2 Main UI Button such as when either of them is pressed it should check the condition whether a animation is already played before by 2nd button available if yes then remove those gameobject from scene using reverse animation else play the default animation attach to the particular button.

Problem is out of 6 case only 4 are getting operational 2 of them are not executing (marked in the code as **Case Not Operational**)

```
Animation anim;
private bool isOpen = false; 
private bool open = false;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animation>();
    //isOpen = false;
    //open = false;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void OnGUI()
{
    isOpen = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(50, 50, 200, 100), isOpen, "IsOpen");
    open = GUI.Toggle(new Rect(65, 65, 200, 100), open, "Open");
}
public void ButtonControl()
{
    string name = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;
    if (name == "Main Button 1")
    {
        if (isOpen == false && open == false)
        {   Debug.Log("False False 1");
            Anim1();
            isOpen = true;
        }
        else if (isOpen == false && open == true) // case not operational
        {   Debug.Log("False True 2");
            ReverseAnim_2();
            open = false;
            Anim1();
            isOpen = true;
        }
        else if(isOpen == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("True 3");
            ReverseAnim_1();
            isOpen = false;
        }
    }


    else if (name == "Main Button 2")
    {
        if (open == false && isOpen == false)
        {   Debug.Log("False False 4");
            Anim2();
            open = true;
        }
        else if(open == false && isOpen == true) // case not operational
        {   Debug.Log("False True 5");
            ReverseAnim_1();
            isOpen = false;
            Anim2();
            open = true;
        }
        else if(open == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("True 6");
            ReverseAnim_2(); 
            open = false;
        }
    }
}

void ReverseAnim_1()
{
    anim["1"].speed = -1;
    anim["1"].time = anim["1"].length;
    anim.Play();
}

void Anim1()
{
    anim["1"].speed = 1;
    anim.Play();
}

void Anim2()
{
    anim["2"].speed = 1;
    anim.Play();
}

void ReverseAnim_2()
{
    anim["2"].speed = -1;
    anim["2"].time = anim["2"].length;
    anim.Play();
}
```

Comment: How is `ButtonControl` called?

Comment: @Ruzihm it is called in inspector section.... UI Button do have Button Script under which on click box is present... from there it is called.

Comment: you can ignore the OnGUI Stuff I just used it for testing purpose.

In Hierarchy, There is canvas -> (UI Button)Main Button1 & Main Button2
Under there inspection panel onclick section i m calling this same script for these two Main Button1 and Main Button 2

Comment: Suppose you start the game, then press button 1. Does "False False 1" print then nothing else?  If so, that's good. Without leaving the game, what prints when you click button 2?

Comment: @Ruzihm Outputs are :- Press button 1 false false 1.... press button 2 false false 4.... and both the menu gets activated on screen which i don't want... I want that it should play that condition which will print false true 5....

Comment: What object is this component attached to? Also, is there only one of this component -- and for reference, what is this component called?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19BGGOje8wQnjPmPodgA994hmelRhYz0y

Here is the image u can see @Ruzihm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two `Main_B2` scripts and they are each tracking their own values for the `isOpen` and `open` fields.

One solution for this could be to make the fields `static` so that they are in common across all instances of `Main_B2`.

```
Animation anim;
private static bool isOpen = false; 
private static bool open = false;
```

If you do this, your code should work as intended - each instance of `Main_B2` would then be referring to the same fields whenever they reference `isOpen` or `open`.

---

With that said, `static` fields can get kind of sloppy if you ever want to try and re-use code so a better option might be to have **only one instance of** `Main_B2` somewhere else such as the `Canvas`, instead of one on each button.

Then you could have in it `public GameObject` fields that you can drag the button objects into, and `private Animation` fields for the animations.:

```
public GameObject button1
public GameObject button2

private Animation anim1
private Animation anim2
```

Then in `Start`:

```
anim1 = button1.GetComponent<Animation>();
anim2 = button2.GetComponent<Animation>();
```

And then wherever you referred to `anim` you would refer to `anim1` or `anim2` instead:

```
void ReverseAnim_1()
{
    anim1.["1"].speed = -1;
    anim1.["1"].time = anim1["1"].length;
    anim1.Play();
}

void Anim1()
{
    anim1["1"].speed = 1;
    anim1.Play();
}

void Anim2()
{
    anim2["2"].speed = 1;
    anim2.Play();
}

void ReverseAnim_2()
{
    anim2["2"].speed = -1;
    anim2["2"].time = anim2["2"].length;
    anim2.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scripts 'anim' variable is an Animation. Normally to adjust animation parameters you set them on an Animator, not Animation. But perhaps your solution can work.

For clarity. An animator organizes how animations play out, when, for how long and how they transition.

I would personally advise you to use an animator with behaviour patterns and transitionings between animations. Instead of the current approach.

Either that or use one of the many Tweening asset packs from the asset store. They are specifically made to create UI effects like what you describe.

At least consider these solutions if you keep being stuck :-)

Comment: I want to try with this method only.